# Output different query results in same table

Tags: google-bigquery

After the recent update, google bigquery now allows querying from country-specific tables.**I wanted to find the number of origins(websites) in the us table containing the word 'space' and display it side by side with a similar result from the Japan table.** The query I'm making is -

```
WITH
 query_1 as 
    (select distinct origin as japan 
     from `chrome-ux-report.country_jp.201712` where 
     origin like "%space%"),
 query_2 as 
    (select distinct origin as usa 
     from `chrome-ux-report.country_us.201712` 
     where origin like "%space%" )
SELECT japan,usa from query_1,query_2
```

But it results in a table having multiple repetitions of the same origin in both the japan and usa column. Another strange thing is that the o/p table contains same number of rows for japan and usa where clearly, the number of sites containing the word 'space' is not same in the 2 tables. I'm using standard sql, not legacy. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
Note: by side by side, I mean there will be two columns, the japan column displaying sites for japan and the usa column displaying results for usa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in BigQuery Standard SQL (that you are using in your query) comma between tables in `FROM` statement mean `CROSS JOIN`.   This explains why `it results in a table having multiple repetitions of the same origin in both the japan and usa column`

Depends on how exactly you want your result to look - you can construct your query in many different ways - for example

```
WITH
 query_1 AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT origin AS japan 
     FROM `chrome-ux-report.country_jp.201712` WHERE 
     origin LIKE "%space%"),
 query_2 AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT origin AS usa 
     FROM `chrome-ux-report.country_us.201712` 
     WHERE origin LIKE "%space%" )
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT japan FROM query_1) AS japan,
  ARRAY(SELECT usa FROM query_2) AS usa
```

Also you can check counts as below

```
WITH
 query_1 AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT origin AS japan 
     FROM `chrome-ux-report.country_jp.201712` WHERE 
     origin LIKE "%space%"),
 query_2 AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT origin AS usa 
     FROM `chrome-ux-report.country_us.201712` 
     WHERE origin LIKE "%space%" )
SELECT 
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT japan FROM query_1)) AS japan_count,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT usa FROM query_2)) AS usa_count
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I'm trying to save the data to google sheets, a message tells me " Result schema contains a record or repeated field". Can you tell me how to overcome this ?

Comment: if you have new question - post it as a new question and someone will be able to answer it :o)

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, this  query is working great for small queries, however when I add more and more countries, it shows the error : resource exceeded during query execution

Comment: You current question was related to how to fix a `multiple repetitions of the same origin in both the japan and usa column` and is what was addressed in my answer. if you have new question  - please post it as a new question and provide all related details so we can answer :o)